# export csv from highcharts

Tags: highcharts, angular2-highcharts

I'm using angular-5,angular2-highcharts version 0.5.5 and highcharts version 6.0.7.

I want to add in my html in not in the chart a button for download the chart in png or csv.

Png one works fine, but I can't got it with csv:

This is my code:

```
downloadPng(): void {   //this one works
   this.chart.exportChart({
      type: 'image/png',
      filename: this.title
    });
}

downloadCsv(): void {   //this one crashes
   this.chart.exportChart({
      type: 'text/csv',
      filename: this.title
    },{
      itemDelimiter: ';',
      csv: this.chart.getCSV() 
    });
}
```

When crashes it redirects to

https://export.highcharts.com/

with this text

```
unexpected return from chart generation - please check your input data
```

I think I need to do something else for csv export. Can anybody help me?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need the [export-data](https://code.highcharts.com/modules/export-data.js) module. It extends a chart with `downloadCSV` method.

```
function downlaodCsv() {
  chart.downloadCSV()
}
```

live example: http://jsfiddle.net/z1j4enox/

Comment: is it possible to change file name?

Comment: I've just realized I also have trouble with png, because when exporting the chart data is removed (thats not removed with chart.downloadCSV()) could you include how to donwload png in your example, please?

Comment: You can set exporting.filename option to change the file name. chart.exportChart() should export the chart to png - see the example http://jsfiddle.net/u32yfm9j/.

Comment: thanks but what you post doesn't work in angular. I can filename in png but I can't in csv. Also in angular "exportChart()" removes the chart data.

Comment: I suppose it might be the issue with the wrapper if you use one. If you post a live example with minimal and complete code, e.g. on plunkr, I will try to find the solution.

Comment: change name in csv is now working, the only remaining problem is exportChart removes data, you can check it by clicking twice to downloadpng button

Comment: It's really crazy how the documentation doesn't really help finding these lines. Thank you so much for your contribution! In several projects, it feels you need a tutorial to understand the tutorial :/